# Troubleshooting Week Start date SQL

Tags: sql-server

I've been using a SQL query line of code that gives the Week Start date beginning on a Monday.  It runs fine for the most part, but came across a particular date (Sunday, 08/08/21) that is being grouped incorrectly.  Can someone help explain what may be causing this?

The line of code I'm using is below:

```sql
FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, a.TicketDate)-2), a.TicketDate)),'MM/dd/yy') as WeekStart
```

| WeekStart | TicketDate |
| --- | --- |
| 08/02/21 | 08/04/21 |
| 08/02/21 | 08/05/21 |
| 08/09/21 | 08/08/21 |
| 08/09/21 | 08/09/21 |
| 08/09/21 | 08/10/21 |

Comment: T-SQL makes some "odd" choices when dealing with weeks; especially when you're using a language that isn't [American] English. I, often, find that using a calendar table can be easier for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing unusual is going on here besides your SQL calculation not actually doing what you think it is, as the maths are incorrect.  If you break your expression down into its constituent parts you will see that Sundays return a `-1` as a result of your `-(datepart(weekday, a.TicketDate)-2)` that throws the `dateadd` off.

If you can't utilise a dates table for this (and the many other things that they make *much* easier) you just need to correct the maths within your expression:

## Query

```
select cast(a.TicketDate as date) as TicketDate
      ,cast(a.PriorMonday as date) as PriorMonday
      ,cast(dateadd(day,1,dateadd(day, -(datepart(weekday, dateadd(day,-1,a.TicketDate))), a.TicketDate)) as date) as Calc
from (values('20210801','20210726')
           ,('20210802','20210802')
           ,('20210803','20210802')
           ,('20210804','20210802')
           ,('20210805','20210802')
           ,('20210806','20210802')
           ,('20210807','20210802')
           ,('20210808','20210802')
           ,('20210809','20210809')
           ,('20210810','20210809')
           ,('20210811','20210809')
           ,('20210812','20210809')
           ,('20210813','20210809')
           ,('20210814','20210809')
           ,('20210815','20210809')
     ) as a(TicketDate,PriorMonday)
```

---

## Output

| TicketDate | PriorMonday | Calc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-01 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-07-26 |
| 2021-08-02 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-08-02 |
| 2021-08-03 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-08-02 |
| 2021-08-04 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-08-02 |
| 2021-08-05 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-08-02 |
| 2021-08-06 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-08-02 |
| 2021-08-07 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-08-02 |
| 2021-08-08 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-08-02 |
| 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |
| 2021-08-10 | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |
| 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |
| 2021-08-12 | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |
| 2021-08-13 | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |
| 2021-08-14 | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |
| 2021-08-15 | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |